# Get the module/File name, where the thread was created?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I used the below code to get the list the threads in the currently running process.

```
Process p=Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var threads=p.Thread;
```

But my requirement is to know the file name or the module name, where the thread is created.

Please guide me to achieve my requirements.

Comment: So far what did you try? Anyway you can't get WHO created the thread, what you have is its current stack trace (so maximum you can get the first function invoked if you're sure they stay in the same assembly).

Comment: I think it matters the `Process` only, not the `Threads`. Each process has some `Modules` attached with. You can access them via `Modules` property of a `Process`.

Comment: i need to know the function name or module name, where the each thread were created..

Comment: if can we get the stack trace details about the thread means, it's enough for me.

Comment: What I use to do is Create the Thread Name as the executing assembly or whatever place i have made the thread.[my own created thread]
Then I get the thread name where i want's to do logging

Comment: You can probably use ThreadLocalStorage to store assemblyname/module etc and then access in your code. Dont think there is a way identify the same in a thread created by someone else's code.

Answer (score 1):

I would punt on getting the file name. It can be done, but it is probably not worth the effort. Instead, set the `Name` property on the `Thread` to the name of the class that created it.

You will be able to see the `Name` value when inspected with the Visual Studio debugger. If you want to get a list of all managed threads in the current process via code then you will need to create your own thread repository. You cannot map a `ProcessThread` to a `Thread` because there is not always a one-to-one relationship between the two.

```
public static class ThreadManager
{
  private List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

  public static Thread StartNew(string name, Action action)
  {
    var thread = new Thread(
      () =>
      {
        lock (threads)
        {
          threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread);
        }
        try
        {
          action();
        }
        finally
        {
          lock (threads)
          {
            threads.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
          }
        }
      });
    thread.Name = name;
    thread.Start();
  }

  public static IEnumerable<Thread> ActiveThreads
  {
    get 
    { 
      lock (threads)
      {
        return new List<Thread>(threads); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it would be used like this.

```
class SomeClass
{
  public void StartOperation()
  {
    string name = typeof(SomeClass).FullName;
    ThreadManager.StartNew(name, () => RunOperation());
  }
}
```

**Update:**

If you are using C# 5.0 or higher you can experiment with the new [Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) attributes.

```
class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    DoSomething();
  }

  private static void DoSomething()
  {
    GetCallerInformation();
  }

  private static void GetCallerInformation(
      [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
      [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
      [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)  
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Member Name: " + memberName);
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + sourceFilePath);
    Console.WriteLine("Line Number: " + sourceLineNumber.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using the below code to get the process thread details, Process p=Process.GetCurrentProcess();  var thread=p.Thread;

Comment: Can we get the stack trace of the thread using the above method?

Comment: @sivaprakash: No, you cannot do that using purely managed code.